# Using file as payload in Advanced REST Client

Tags: json, rest, google-chrome, advanced-rest-client

I'm trying to work with the Advanced REST Client of Google.
I installed the extension, and I can work with it.
Now I wanted to use a JSON-file as input for my payload.

The JSON-file looks as follows :

```
{"UserName":"", "UserPassword":"","SetDebug":true}
```

The Content-Type is set to application/json.

But when I try to send the request I get the following error:

> {
>   "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource."
>   }

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The ARC seems to override your Content-Type selection sometimes, changing it to *multipart-form-data*. If you select Files for the body and pick a file, it shows a message saying:

> The Content-Type header will finally be changed to "multipart/form-data" during the request.

When you submit the request, it does exactly that: changes the Content-Type header. You can confirm this by looking in the Request Headers part of the output display.

I don't know if there's any way to stop it doing this :(-